# Frequent ON OFF in SSR

Tags: relay, temperature-sensor, display, pid

I am working on a project on Arduino OLED MAX6675 thermocouple and SSR for my oven.
My problem is when my SSR goes in LOW or HIGH state it  turn ON and OFF several times before going to permanent HIGH or LOW state. 
This make my load(Heater) on and off many times. Since the temperature crosses the set-point to change the output state, the process temperature will be cycling rapidly, going from below set-point to above, and back below.
This frequent ON OFF will damage my SSR and heater.
My Question.
Is there any hardware or software solution. To reduce the frequency of ON OFF .
I can’t increase  the delay() time because it make my button input slow.
My codes are below.

```c++
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include "max6675.h"

//oled
//oled i2c addresss
#define OLED_ADDR 0x3C
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(-1);
// 128 x 64 pixel display
#define SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT 64

//MAX6675
//Pin initialization
int so = 2;
int cs = 3;
int sck = 4;
MAX6675 thermocouple(sck, cs, so);
float current_temp;
int set_temp;
int const h_temp = 2;

//Button
int button_up = 7;
int button_down = 8;
int button_upv;
int button_downv;

//SSR
int ssr_u = 10;
int ssr_d = 12;

void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
    delay(1000);

    // initialize and clear display
    display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(8, 20);
    display.println("Welcome..");
    display.display();
    display.clearDisplay();
    delay(1000);

    //Button
    pinMode(button_up, INPUT);
    pinMode(button_down, INPUT);
    set_temp = 20;
    pinMode(ssr_u, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ssr_d, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    current_temp = thermocouple.readCelsius();
    delay(100);
    button_upv = digitalRead(button_up);
    button_downv = digitalRead(button_down);

    //button
    if (button_upv == HIGH && set_temp < 180) {
        set_temp = set_temp + 5;
    }
    if (button_downv == HIGH && set_temp > 20) {
        set_temp = set_temp - 5;
    }

    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(5, 10);
    display.println(current_temp);
    display.setCursor(5, 30);
    display.println(set_temp);

    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(30, 40);
    if (button_upv == HIGH) {
        display.println("Up");
    }
    if (button_downv == HIGH) {
        display.println("Down");
    }
    display.display();

    //SSR
    if (current_temp < set_temp - h_temp) {
        digitalWrite(ssr_u, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ssr_d, HIGH);
        delay(500);
    }
    if else(current_temp > set_temp + h_temp) {
        digitalWrite(ssr_u, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ssr_d, LOW);
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Which arduino board do you use? Are you using a 3.3v arduino board and a counterfeit ssr? Please explain better what you have and how it is powered. Google for hysteresis. You need to put some hysteresis into your sketch.

Comment: I am using pro mini 5v and 40 amp SSR.

Comment: the keyword is hysteresis http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=526806.0

Comment: Is there any hardware solution like adding a capacitor so that voltage remaining constant for few seconds

Comment: Hysteresis will just be way easier in software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement hysteresis. Set two temperature points around set_temp. One a little higher to be a limit for turning the heater off and a one a little lower then set_temp to turn the heater on.

You only need to change your if else condition a little

```
if (current_temp < set_temp - HYST_VALUE) {
  digitalWrite(ssr_u, HIGH);
} else if (current_temp > set_temp + HYST_VALUE) {
  digitalWrite(ssr_u, LOW);
}
```

you could start with

```
int const HYST_VALUE = 1;
```

Comment: Is there any hardware solution like adding a capacitor so that voltage remaining constant for few seconds

Comment: this is a regulation problem, not simply solvable by hardware. the temperature could oscillate around your set temperature long time. implementing hysteresis is how it is done in all thermostats

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Hello juraj I tried the same as you said but this code freeze loop somewhere. I am doing something wrong somewhere please help.I tried the same code.

Comment: Hello juraj I also change my sketch in question please check it.

Comment: you have < twice and it is `} else if (`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83681/discussion-between-himanshu-and-juraj).